# send update message from asp.net server to client webpage

Tags: asp.net

If I want to implement something similar to a stockticker, should I use a timer, or is there a way to update an element inside a webpage(like a gridview), when there is a changeon the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Description

I strongly suggest to use SignalR. The benefit is that you dont think about browser compatibilty. It uses polling, long polling or websockets depending on what the browser supports. It allows to push changes to the client, is opensource and easy to set up. Check out [SignalR Stock Ticker Sample](http://vimeo.com/31938189)

> **SignalR** - Async library for .NET to help build real-time, multi-user interactive web applications.

You can instal it using nuget.

> PM> Install-Package SignalR

#### More Information

- [Asynchronous scalable web applications with real-time persistent long-running connections with SignalR](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx)
- [SignalR](http://signalr.net/)
- [Github - SignalR / SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR)

Comment: SignalR uses websockets too, if possible. The problem with websockets is the different implementations each browser made. I think we have to wait very long till every browser supports websockets in a similar way.